# Read complex JSON files in python and store in dataframe

Tags: python, json

I am new to python.

I have two set of JSON output files and I need to convert them to csv or dataframe.

```
File 1
{
"lastFileTime" : "2020-06-08T00:23:05.986-07:00",
"lastFileTimeMs" : "1591600985986",
"statNames" : ["stat1", "stat2", "stat3", "stat4", "stat5", "stat6", "stat7", "stat8", "stat9"],
"values" : [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
}

Desired Output
stat1,stat2,stat3,stat4,stat5,stat6,stat7,stat8,stat9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

So I need to discard lastFileTime and lastFileTimeMs and read display in csv.  I tried the following:

```
# Import the json module
import json

# Open a json file into a json object
with open('a.json') as F:
    json_data = json.loads(F.read())

# Print loaded json object
print(json_data)
```

But I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 9, in <module>
    json_data = json.loads(F.read())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any help is appreciated... The other problem I have is that I am tied to python 2.7.5 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
import itertools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    jsons = json.load(open("config2.json"))
    lastFileTime = jsons["lastFileTime"]
    lastFileTimeMs = jsons["lastFileTimeMs"]
    statNames = jsons["statNames"]
    values = jsons["values"]
    print(lastFileTime)
    print(lastFileTimeMs)
    list_to_str_statNames = ' '.join([str(element) for element in statNames])
    print(str(list_to_str_statNames))
    v1 = values[0]
    list_to_str_v1 = ' '.join([str(element) for element in v1])
    print(list_to_str_v1)
    v2 = values[1]
    list_to_str_v2 = ' '.join([str(element) for element in v2])
    print(list_to_str_v2)
```

Comment: This code will work on Python 2.7 and 3+.
Make a note of jsons variable and json package.
jsons = json.load(open("config.json"))

Comment: Hi, thanks but the output is coming like: # python s.py 
2020-06-08T00:23:05.986-07:00
1591600985986
stat1 stat2 stat3 stat4 stat5 stat6 stat7 stat8 stat9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: comment these lines.
#print(lastFileTime)
#print(lastFileTimeMs)
and add below line
print("\n")

Comment: code has been updated
2020-06-08T00:23:05.986-07:00
1591600985986
stat1 stat2 stat3 stat4 stat5 stat6 stat7 stat8 stat9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: To store it in dataframe..
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(jsons))
    print(df)

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm now... I drilled down into my original error and it is related to a float value.